# Different line break behavior in FF Mac and FF Windows

Tags: javascript, css

Why I have a different line break behavior in Firefox Mac and Firefox Windows. How can I make sure that I have the same line break in both platforms?

It is important for me to use decimal places.

You can see my example code and my screenshots [on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nAS3R/2/)

## Sample HTML code

```
<div style="width:380px;height:81px;word-wrap:break-word;font-family:Arial;font-size:30.24px;">
<span>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</span>
```

## Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Use a proper reset.css?

Comment: Well for a start - Windows has Arial, a Mac doesn't, so will use another font. Or if it does, it's not quite the same as the Windows version.

Comment: "It is important for me to use decimal places." In a font-size....that's a **very** brittle design then.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts used may differ, or browsers may use the same font but render it differently, causing small variation in widths of characters.

To get the same line breaks, you would use forced breaks `<br>` where you want them and wrap the rest in `<nobr>...</nobr>` or do the same in CSS. This would of course be very primitive and inflexible.

Consider describing an actual problem instead. What is the real content and how should it be formatted?